# how SSO will use with iframe to load an external application in salesforce

Tags: apex, community, integration, aws

I have done the setup of connected app and also done the setup at aws end. when i try opening that connected app directly and after that i click on iframe included tab, it is loading fine. but when - without going that connected app - if I try opening my iframe included tab, it is giving me below error:

> Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

I am not sure how i should link SSO and iframe together to render that application smoothly for authenticated users. right now there is no connection between my iframe tab and that connected app, which i created.

I need help in understanding how i should link that connected app with the iframe, so that i can use SSO with iframe to do the communication between sfdc and aws.